Dynamic factor models with time-varying loadings in python
I'm trying to model dynamic factor model with time-varying loadings in python, specifically, a TVP-FAVAR model in python. I've looked at the statsmodels statspace sm.tsa.DynamicFactor or sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel classes. I've found use case examples of TVP-VAR and FAVAR in statsmodels, but not for TVP-FAVAR. For a simple AR(1) case, the model can be expressed as:



I have tried putting the beta term into a state equation, but the result doesn't look linear...


The paper that I'm reading implemented the model in matlab, using Kalman filters, but if statsmodels is a no-go, I might have to resort to using MCMC (PyMC could probably help model the non-linear stuff). Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

As you said, this is not linear. You may have to look into extended Kalman filters.

So after going over the paper of Gary Koop and Dimitris Korobilis, for the specific model that I needed in "A new index of financial conditions," I realized that the authors use an indirect method for the estimation. Specifically, a 3-step algorithm. First, they initialize the parameters and estimate a PCA with one component (proxy index). Then they use it to get some time-varying parameters. Then they use “Variance Discounting,” to get the covariance matrices over time. Finally, using those we get the final (intended) time-varying coefficients using kalman filtering and smoothing. After the model is estimated we can generate/draw the f_t states. I used the Matlab code that they shared to implement the model in python. See the full code below:

class TVP_FAVAR():
    # Function to estimate time-varying loadings, coefficients, and covariances
    # from a TVP-FAVAR, conditional on feeding in an estimate of the factors
    # (Principal Components). This function runs the Kalman filter and smoother
    # for all time-varying parameters using an adaptive algorithm (EWMA filter
    # for the covariances).
    # Written by Dimitris Korobilis, 2012, edited by YV
    def __init__(self, endog, exog, nlags=4, nfactors=1):
        nstates = exog.shape[1]
        t, nvars = endog.shape
        self.nlags = nlags
        self.nmacro = nstates - nfactors
        nstates_all = nstates*self.nlags
        nVAR = self.nlags*(nstates**2)

        # setup: lambda
        self.lambda_pred = np.zeros((nvars, nstates, t))
        self.lambda_update = np.zeros((nvars, nstates, t))

        for i in range(t):
            self.lambda_pred[:nstates, :nstates, i] = np.eye(nstates)
            self.lambda_update[:nstates, :nstates, i] = np.eye(nstates)

        # setup: beta
        self.beta_pred = np.zeros((nVAR, t))
        self.beta_update = np.zeros((nVAR, t))

        # setup: states
        self.Rl_t = np.zeros((nstates, nstates, nvars, t))
        self.Sl_t = np.zeros((nstates, nstates, nvars, t))
        self.Rb_t = np.zeros((nVAR, nVAR, t))
        self.Sb_t = np.zeros((nVAR, nVAR, t))

        # setup: expectations
        self.x_t_pred = np.zeros((t, nvars))
        self.e_t = np.zeros((nvars, t))
        self.lambda_t = np.zeros((nvars, nstates, t))
        self.beta_t = np.zeros((nstates_all, nstates_all, t))

        # setup: covariance
        self.Q_t = np.zeros((nstates, nstates, t))
        self.V_t = np.zeros((nvars, nvars, t))

        # define lags of the factors to be used in the state (VAR) equation
        lf = LagFeatures(periods=list(range(1, self.nlags+1)), drop_original=True)
        xx = lf.fit_transform(exog).dropna()
        yy = exog.loc[xx.index].copy()
        self.xx = np.array(xx)
        self.yy = np.array(yy)
        self.exog = np.array(exog)
        self.endog = np.array(endog)
        Flagtemp, m = create_RHS_NI(self.xx.copy(), nstates, self.nlags, t)
        self.Flag = np.concatenate((np.zeros((nstates_all, nVAR)), Flagtemp), axis=0)

    def kalman_setup(self, priors):
        # init
        t, nvars = self.endog.shape
        self.Q_t[:, :, 0] = priors['Q_0']
        self.V_t[:, :, 0] = np.diag(np.diag(priors['V_0']))
        self.lambda_pred[:, :, 0] = priors['lambda_0_mean']
        self.beta_pred[:, 0] = priors['beta_0_mean']
        self.beta_update[:, 0] = self.beta_pred[:, 0]
        self.Rb_t[:, :, 0] = priors['beta_0_var']
        for i in range(self.nmacro, nvars):
            self.Rl_t[:, :, i, 0] = priors['lambda_0_var']

    def kalman_update_coeffs(self, t):
        nstates = self.exog.shape[1]
        # Update VAR coefficients conditional on Principal Componets estimates
        Rx = self.Rb_t[:, :, t] @ self.Flag[t*nstates:(t+1)*nstates, :].T
        KV_b = self.Q_t[:, :, t] + self.Flag[t*nstates:(t+1)*nstates, :]  @ Rx
        KG = Rx @ np.linalg.inv(KV_b)
        beta_adj = KG @ (self.exog[t, :].T - self.Flag[t*nstates:(t+1)*nstates, :] @ self.beta_pred[:, t])
        self.beta_update[:, t] = self.beta_pred[:, t] + beta_adj
        Sb_adj = KG @ (self.Flag[t*nstates:(t+1)*nstates, :] @ self.Rb_t[:, :, t])
        self.Sb_t[:, :, t] = self.Rb_t[:, :, t] - Sb_adj

    def kalman_filter_early(self, t, decays, priors):
        nstates = self.exog.shape[1]
        exog_i = self.exog[t, :]

        # priors
        self.beta_pred[:, t] = priors['beta_0_mean']
        self.beta_update[:, t] = self.beta_pred[:, t]
        self.Rb_t[:, :, t] = priors['beta_0_var']

        # expectations
        Gf_t = 0.1*(exog_i.reshape(-1, 1) @ exog_i.reshape(1, -1))
        if t > 0:
            self.Q_t[:, :, t] = decays[1]*self.Q_t[:, :, t-1] + (1-decays[1])*Gf_t[:nstates, :nstates]

    def kalman_filter(self, t, decays):
        nstates = self.exog.shape[1]
        nstates_all = nstates*self.nlags
        yy_i = self.yy[t-self.nlags]
        xx_i = self.xx[t-self.nlags]

        # expectations
        ee_i = (yy_i - xx_i @ self.B[:nstates, :nstates_all].T)
        Gf_t = ee_i.reshape(-1, 1) @ ee_i.reshape(1, -1)
        self.Q_t[:, :, t] = decays[1]*self.Q_t[:, :, t-1] + (1-decays[1])*Gf_t[:nstates, :nstates]

        # update beta
        self.beta_pred[:, t] = self.beta_update[:, t-1]
        self.Rb_t[:, :, t] = (1 / decays[3]) * self.Sb_t[:, :, t-1]

    def kalman_predict(self, t, decays):
        nstates = self.exog.shape[1]
        nvars = self.endog.shape[1]
        n_undefined_rows = nstates*(self.nlags-1)
        p = self.nmacro

        # Kalman predict steps
        if t > 0:
            self.lambda_pred[:, :, t] = self.lambda_update[:, :, t-1]
            self.Rl_t[:, :, :, t] = (1/decays[2])*self.Sl_t[:, :, :, t-1]

        # One step ahead prediction based on PC factor
        self.x_t_pred[t, :] = self.lambda_pred[:, :, t] @ self.exog[t, :].T

        # Prediction error
        self.e_t[:, t] = self.endog[t, :] - self.x_t_pred[t, :]

        # Get the measurement error variance
        self.A_t = self.e_t[self.nmacro:, t].reshape(-1, 1) @ self.e_t[self.nmacro:, t].reshape(1, -1)
        if t > 0:
            self.V_t[p:, p:, t] = decays[0]*self.V_t[p:, p:, t-1] + (1-decays[0])*np.diag(np.diag(self.A_t))

        # Update loadings conditional on Principal Components estimates
        for i in range(self.nmacro, nvars):
            Rx = self.Rl_t[:nstates, :nstates, i, t] @ self.exog[t, :nstates].T
            KV_l = self.V_t[i, i, t] + self.exog[t, :nstates] @ Rx
            KG = Rx / KV_l
            lambda_adj = KG * (self.endog[t, i].T - self.lambda_pred[i, :nstates, t] @ self.exog[t, :nstates].T)
            self.lambda_update[i, :nstates, t] = self.lambda_pred[i, :nstates, t] + lambda_adj
            Sl_adj = KG.reshape(-1, 1) @ (self.exog[t, :nstates] @ self.Rl_t[:nstates, :nstates, i, t]).reshape(1, -1)
            self.Sl_t[:nstates, :nstates, i, t] = self.Rl_t[:nstates, :nstates, i, t] - Sl_adj

        # update coeffs
        if t >= self.nlags:
            self.kalman_update_coeffs(t)

        # Assign coefficients
        biga = self.beta_update[:, t].reshape(nstates, self.nlags, nstates).transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(nstates, -1)
        b_other = np.concatenate((np.eye(n_undefined_rows), np.zeros((n_undefined_rows, nstates))), axis=1)
        self.B = np.concatenate((biga, b_other), axis=0)
        self.lambda_t[:, :, t] = self.lambda_update[:, :, t]
        if np.max(np.abs(np.linalg.eig(self.B)[0])) < 0.9999:
            self.beta_t[:, :, t] = self.B
        else:
            self.beta_t[:, :, t] = self.beta_t[:, :, t-1]
            self.beta_update[:, t] = 0.95*self.beta_update[:, t-1]

    def smoother_setup(self, t):
        self.lambda_new = 0*self.lambda_update
        self.lambda_new[:, :, t] = self.lambda_update[:, :, t]
        self.beta_new = 0*self.beta_update
        self.beta_new[:, t] = self.beta_update[:, t]
        self.Q_t_new = 0*self.Q_t
        self.Q_t_new[:, :, t] = self.Q_t[:, :, t]
        self.V_t_new = 0*self.V_t
        self.V_t_new[:, :, t] = self.V_t[:, :, t]

    def kalman_smoother(self, t):
        # init
        nstates = self.exog.shape[1]
        nvars = self.endog.shape[1]
        p = self.nmacro

        # smooth lambda
        self.lambda_new[:nstates, :, t] = self.lambda_update[:nstates, :, t]
        for i in range(nstates, nvars):
            Ul_t = self.Sl_t[:nstates, :nstates, i, t] @ np.linalg.inv(self.Rl_t[:nstates, :nstates, i, t+1])
            lambda_adj = (self.lambda_new[i, :nstates, t+1] - self.lambda_pred[i, :nstates, t+1]) @ Ul_t.T
            self.lambda_new[i, :nstates, t] = self.lambda_update[i, :nstates, t] + lambda_adj

        # smooth beta
        if np.sum(self.Rb_t[:, :, t+1]) == 0:
            self.beta_new[:, t] = self.beta_update[:, t]
        else:
            Ub_t = self.Sb_t[:, :, t] @ np.linalg.inv(self.Rb_t[:, :, t+1])
            self.beta_new[:, t] = self.beta_update[:, t] + Ub_t @ (self.beta_new[:, t+1] - self.beta_pred[:, t+1])

        # smooth Q_t
        self.Q_t_new[:, :, t] = 0.9*self.Q_t[:, :, t] + 0.1*self.Q_t_new[:, :, t+1]

        # smooth V_t
        self.V_t_new[p:, p:, t] = 0.9*self.V_t[p:, p:, t] + 0.1*self.V_t_new[p:, p:, t+1]

    def kalman_reassign_coefficients(self, t):
        nstates = self.exog.shape[1]
        n_undefined_rows = nstates*(self.nlags-1)
        biga = self.beta_new[:, t].reshape(nstates, self.nlags, nstates).transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(nstates, -1)
        b_other = np.concatenate((np.eye(n_undefined_rows), np.zeros((n_undefined_rows, nstates))), axis=1)
        B = np.concatenate((biga, b_other), axis=0)
        self.lambda_t[:, :, t] = self.lambda_new[:, :, t]
        self.beta_t[:, :, t] = B

    def fit(self, nfactors, decays, priors):
        # initialize matrices for filtering
        t = self.endog.shape[0]
        self.kalman_setup(priors)

        # perform predictions at time t=0
        self.kalman_predict(0, decays)

        # 1. Kalman filter
        for irep in range(1, t):
            # Update the state covariances,
            # get the variance of the factor and update Q[t]
            if irep <= self.nlags:
                self.kalman_filter_early(irep, decays, priors)
            else:
                self.kalman_filter(irep, decays)
            self.kalman_predict(irep, decays)

        # 2. Kalman smoother
        self.smoother_setup(t-1)
        for irep in range(t-2, -1, -1):
            self.kalman_smoother(irep)

        # using smoothed values for beta and lambda
        for irep in range(t):
            self.kalman_reassign_coefficients(irep)
        return self.beta_t, self.beta_new, self.lambda_t, self.V_t, self.Q_t

    def kalman_factor_update(self, t):
        # setup
        nstates = self.exog.shape[1]

        # One step ahead prediction based on Kalman factor
        self.x_t_predf[t, :] = self.lambda_t[:, :, t] @ self.factor_pred[:nstates, t]

        # Prediction error
        self.ef_t[:, t] = self.endog[t, :] - self.x_t_predf[t, :]

        # Update the factors conditional on the estimate of lambda_t and beta_t
        KV_f = self.V_t[:, :, t] + self.lambda_t[:, :, t] @ self.Rf_t[:nstates, :nstates, t] @ self.lambda_t[:, :, t].T
        KG = (self.Rf_t[:nstates, :nstates, t] @ self.lambda_t[:, :, t].T) @ np.linalg.inv(KV_f)
        self.factor_update[:nstates, t] = self.factor_pred[:nstates, t] + KG @ self.ef_t[:, t]
        self.Sf_t[:nstates, :nstates, t] = self.Rf_t[:nstates, :nstates, t] - KG @ (self.lambda_t[:, :, t] @ self.Rf_t[:nstates, :nstates, t])

    def factor_filter(self, priors):
        # setup
        t, nvars = self.endog.shape
        nstates = self.exog.shape[1]
        nstates_all = nstates*self.nlags

        # init
        self.factor_pred = np.zeros((nstates_all, t))
        self.factor_update = np.zeros((nstates_all, t))
        self.Rf_t = np.zeros((nstates_all, nstates_all, t))
        self.Sf_t = np.zeros((nstates_all, nstates_all, t))
        self.x_t_predf = np.zeros((t, nvars))
        self.ef_t = np.zeros((nvars, t))

        # priors
        self.factor_pred[:, 0] = priors['factor_0_mean']
        self.Rf_t[:, :, 0] = priors['factor_0_var']
        self.kalman_factor_update(0)

        # filtering step
        for irep in range(1, t):
            self.factor_pred[:, irep] = self.beta_t[:, :, irep-1] @ self.factor_update[:, irep-1]
            Sfb_t = self.beta_t[:, :, irep-1] @ self.Sf_t[:, :, irep-1] @ self.beta_t[:, :, irep-1].T
            Q_t_sparse = np.concatenate((self.Q_t[:, :, irep], np.zeros((nstates, nstates*(self.nlags-1)))), axis=1)
            Q_t_sparse = np.concatenate((Q_t_sparse, np.zeros((nstates*(self.nlags-1), nstates*nlags))), axis=0)
            self.Rf_t[:, :, irep] = Sfb_t + Q_t_sparse
            self.kalman_factor_update(irep)

    def factor_smoother(self):
        # setup
        t, nvars = self.endog.shape
        nstates = self.exog.shape[1]

        # fixed-interval smoother for the factors
        self.factor_new = 0*self.factor_update
        self.factor_new[:, t-1] = self.factor_update[:, t-1]
        self.Sf_t_new = 0*self.Sf_t
        self.Sf_t_new[:, :, t-1] = self.Sf_t[:, :, t-1]

        # smoothing
        for irep in range(t-2, -1, -1):
            self.Z_t = self.Sf_t[:, :, irep] @ self.beta_t[:, :, irep].T
            U_t = np.squeeze(self.Z_t[:nstates, :nstates] @ np.linalg.inv(self.Rf_t[:nstates, :nstates, irep+1]))
            factor_adj = U_t @ (self.factor_new[:nstates, irep+1] - self.factor_pred[:nstates, irep+1])
            self.factor_new[:nstates, irep] = self.factor_update[:nstates, irep] + factor_adj
            Sf_adj = U_t @ (self.Sf_t[:nstates, :nstates, irep+1] - self.Rf_t[:nstates, :nstates, irep+1]) @ U_t.T
            self.Sf_t_new[:nstates, :nstates, irep] = self.Sf_t[:nstates, :nstates, irep] + Sf_adj
        self.factor_new = self.factor_new[:nstates].T

    def gen_factors(self, priors):
        self.factor_filter(priors)
        self.factor_smoother()
        return self.factor_new, self.Sf_t_new

def create_RHS_NI(YY, nstates, nlags, t):
    K = nlags*(nstates**2)  # K is the number of elements in the state vector
    # Create x_t matrix
    # first find the zeros in matrix x_t
    x_t = np.zeros(((t-nlags)*nstates, K))
    for i in range(t-nlags):
        ztemp = np.array([]).reshape(nstates, -1)
        for j in range(nlags):
            xtemp = YY[i, j*nstates:(j+1)*nstates]
            xtemp = np.kron(np.eye(nstates), xtemp)
            ztemp = np.concatenate((ztemp, xtemp), axis=1)
        x_t[i*nstates:(i+1)*nstates, :] = ztemp
    return x_t, K

def Minn_prior_KOOP(gamma, nstates, nlags, nvars):
    # This is the version of the Minnesota prior with no dependence on the
    # standard deviations of the univariate regressions. This prior allows
    # online estimation and forecasting of the large TVP-VAR.

    # 1. Minnesota Mean on VAR regression coefficients
    A_prior = np.concatenate((0.9*np.eye(nstates),
                              np.zeros(((nlags-1)*nstates, nstates))), axis=0).T
    a_prior = A_prior.T.reshape(-1)

    # 2. Minnesota Variance on VAR regression coefficients
    # Create an array of dimensions nvars x nstates, which will contain the nvars diagonal
    # elements of the covariance matrix, in each of the nstates equations.
    V_i = np.zeros((int(nvars/nstates), nstates))

    for i in range(nstates):
        for j in range(int(nvars/nstates)):
            V_i[j, i] = gamma / (np.ceil((j+1)/nstates))**2

    # 3. Now V (MINNESOTA VARIANCE) is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements of V_i
    V_prior = np.diag(V_i.reshape(-1))  # this is the prior variance of the vector alpha
    return a_prior, V_prior


Usage:
# step 1: Update Parameters Conditional on PC
# the  decays include:
# 1) decay factor for measurement error variance
# 2) decay factor for factor error variance
# 3) decay factor for loadings error variance
# 4) decay factor for VAR coefficients error variance
decays = np.array([0.96, 0.96, 0.99, 0.99])
nfactors = 1
nlags = 4
nstates = YF.shape[1]
nmacro = nstates - nfactors
t, nvars = YX.shape
nstates_all = nstates*nlags
nVAR = nlags*(nstates**2)  # number of VAR parameters

# Priors
priors = {}

# initial condition on the factors
priors['factor_0_mean'] = np.zeros(nstates_all)
priors['factor_0_var'] = 10*np.eye(nstates_all)

# initial condition on lambda_t
priors['lambda_0_mean'] = np.zeros((nvars, nstates))
priors['lambda_0_var'] = 1*np.eye(nstates)

# initial condition on beta_t
gamma = 0.1
b_prior, Vb_prior = Minn_prior_KOOP(gamma, nstates, nlags, nVAR)  # Obtain a Minnesota-type prior
priors['beta_0_mean'] = b_prior
priors['beta_0_var'] = Vb_prior

# initial condition on the covariance matrices
priors['V_0'] = 0.1*np.eye(nvars)
priors['V_0'][:nmacro, :nmacro] = 0
priors['Q_0'] = 0.1*np.eye(nstates)

# modeling
tvp_favar_korobilis = TVP_FAVAR(YX, YF, nlags, nfactors)
beta_t, beta_new, lambda_t, V_t, Q_t = tvp_favar_korobilis.fit(decays, priors)
factor_new, Sf_t_new = tvp_favar_korobilis.gen_factors(priors)
S_knk = pd.DataFrame(factor_new, index=YF.index, columns=YF.columns)

